# Definition of electron density in DFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-chemistry, density-functional-theory

I read that the electron density used for density functional theory in a system of $N$ electrons with wavefunction $\psi$ is defined as

$$\rho(r)=N\int d^3r_2\dots d^3r_N \psi^*(r,r_2,\dots r_N)\psi(r,r_2,\dots r_N) $$

this definition seems weirdly asymmetrical to me. Why is the first coordinate special? How can I interpret this definition physically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total density is the sum of each particle's density  $\rho(r) = \sum_i^N \rho_i(r)$ with
$$ 
\rho_i (r) = \int d^3r_1...d^3r_{i-1}d^3r_{i+1}...d^3r_n |\psi(r_1, ... r_{i-1}, r, r_{i+1}, ..., r_n)|^2.
$$
In DFT, the wave function is a [Slater determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater_determinant) and is thus antisymmetrized, reflecting the indiscernibility of fermions as $\rho_i(r) = \rho_1(r)$. We find
$$
\rho(r) = N\rho_1(r)
$$
which is another form for your equation of $\rho(r)$.

Comment: ah, so the $N$ terms comes from $\rho(r)=\sum_{i=1}^N \rho_i(r)$ where by $\rho_i(r)$ I mean that we integrate on all the particles except particle $i$, but since exchanging two particles just changes the sign of the wavefunction and the integral only depends on the norm of $\psi$, the $N$ terms are all equal, is this correct? I'm still not sure of the physical meaning, as this sum of probabilities is greater than $1$ it is not a probability

Comment: The integral in it-self is the probability of finding the first particle at $r$. The wavefunction is normalized to one, while the integral of the density gives the number of particles in total, that's why you have a $N$. You are right in your first statement.

Comment: I rewrote an answer including your remarks, thanks!

Comment: In DFT, the total electron density is $\rho(\mathbf{r})=\sum_{\sigma}\sum_{i}^{N}n_i|\psi_i(\mathbf{r},\sigma)|^2$, where $\sigma$ represent the spin variable. Also, in Kohn-Sham DFT, the density is $\rho(\mathbf{r})=\sum_{\sigma}\sum_i^N|\psi_i(\mathbf{r},\sigma)|^2$. The latter form (with $n_i=1$ for $N$ orbitals and $0$ for the rest) describes exactly $N$ non-interacting electrons.

Comment: I saw that you joined Matter Modeling SE and for a second thought that you were [Michel Gingras](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=2RVaxVEAAAAJ)!!! Also, hi @Verktaj!

Answer (score 8):

In a one particle system, the probability of finding the electron between $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}+d\mathbf{r}$ is $|\Psi(\mathbf{r})|^2d\mathbf{r}$, with the probability density $\rho(\mathbf{r})=|\Psi(\mathbf{r})|^2$.

In a many-electron system, the probability of finding electron 1 in the volume element $d\mathbf{r}_1$ at $\mathbf{r}_1$, electron 2 in the volume element $d\mathbf{r}_2$ at $\mathbf{r}_2$, and so on, is $|\Psi(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N)|^2d\mathbf{r}_1 d\mathbf{r}_2\dots d\mathbf{r}_N$. Therefore, the probability of finding electron 1 in the volume element $d\mathbf{r}_1$ at $\mathbf{r}_1$ and the other electrons elsewhere is
$$P(1)=\left[\int|\Psi(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N)|^2 d\mathbf{r}_2\dots d\mathbf{r}_N\right]d\mathbf{r}_1=\rho(\mathbf{r}_1)d\mathbf{r}_1$$
This probability is exactly the same for all electrons, because they are **indistinguishable**, so we don't care about the label. Thus, the probability density of finding **an** electron in the volume element $d\mathbf{r}$ at $\mathbf{r}$ and the other $N-1$ electrons elsewhere is $N$ times the probability to find one of the electrons at that region. That is,
$$\rho(\mathbf{r})=N\int|\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_2,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N)|^2 d\mathbf{r}_2\dots d\mathbf{r}_N$$