# The form of electronic density in DFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-functional-theory

I started to study density functional theory, and I saw that in general the eletronic density for a system of $N$ electrons is written as

$$\rho(\textbf{r}) = \langle \psi | \sum_{i=1}^{N} \delta(\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}_{i}) | \psi \rangle,$$

where $\textbf{r}_{i}$ is the position of the $i$th electron. I would like to know why it is written in this way, what is the physical interpretation of this quantite and why I can say that it is the electronic density.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The electron density is defined by
$$\rho(\mathbf{r})=N\int\Psi(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_2,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N)\Psi^*(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}_2,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N)d\mathbf{r}_2\dots d\mathbf{r}_N,$$
as the probability density of the probability of finding one electron at $\mathbf{r}$ and the other $N-1$ electrons elsewhere.

Now, you could use the properties of Dirac's delta and indistinguishability of electrons to have
$$\rho(\mathbf{r})=\int\Psi(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N)\Psi^*(\mathbf{r}_1,\mathbf{r}_2,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N)\left(\sum_i^N\delta(\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r})\right)d\mathbf{r}_1d\mathbf{r}_2\dots d\mathbf{r}_N \\=\langle\Psi|\left(\sum_i^N\delta(\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r})\right)|\Psi\rangle$$
In addition, you should note that the definition of the density operator is $\hat{\rho}=\sum_i^{N}\delta(\mathbf{r}_i-\mathbf{r})$ in a continuous basis. Thus, the electron density is the expectation value of the density operator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it's everything almost clear to me, but I would like to understand the first thing you wrote, that is, why this is the density probability of finding one electron in position $\textbf{r}$. Actually, I think my doubt is about the fundamentals of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @AlfredV Recently, I answered a similar question on SE about the definition of the electron density. You should see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/497324/definition-of-electron-density-in-dft/527571#527571).